# Need to remove the Input field

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to remove the Input field element, when the type is hidden, when I'm selecting **hidden** type for control type in another tab from **autocomplete** type, the value is getting hide in display. but in the console(F12) is showing like below with the value:

```
<div id="ember30156" class="ember-view hidden field" core-role="utility-field" aria-label="Non hidden">
<input id="ember30193" class="ember-view ember-text-field hidden text-field component" type="hidden" name="non-hidden" value="I am Hidden">
</div>
```

In the network field also showing like below with the value

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryMUmkbDAG6Iw0D4Xj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="hidden"

I am Hidden
------WebKitFormBoundaryMUmkbDAG6Iw0D4Xj
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rc"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryMUmkbDAG6Iw0D4Xj--
```

But I need to hide the values from the both element and network tab of console. Here is my code

```
Core.view.Form.Field.extend()
    .named('Core.view.Form.Field.hidden')
    .reopen({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#each value in view.model.values}}{{view view.field name=view.model.name value=value}}{{/each}}'),
        field: Ember.TextField.extend({
            type: "hidden",
            attributeBindings: ['name', 'value'],
            classNames: 'hidden',
            noLabel: true
        })
    });
```

I'm new to the ember.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?  As far as I know there is no way to have a value in a hidden element and hide it from inspection in the console.  Does not matter what script library you are using.  

If you need a value for your script but don't want the user to see it then consider pulling it in on the script side as needed or put it in a cookie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by hiding it from the network, but to make the input not show up at all in the DOM, you can use an if helper in your template hbs:

```
{{#if showInput}}
  {{input value=something}}
{{/if}}
```

Then in the component JavaScript:

```
this.set(‘showInput`, true)
```

to reveal it. There are examples of the if helper in [the docs](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/if?anchor=if) and [the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/templates/conditionals/). I recommend doing the official [tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/tutorial/ember-cli/) as you are learning. Good luck :)

*This answer applies from 1.13 to 3.x at least.*